# Is it legal to divide an equation by a trigonometric expression which may equal zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

I have the following function: $f(x) = \cos(4x) + \sin(4x)$ in the range of $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Obviously as you can see this function is defined for every $x$. Let's say I want to find the extremum points for this function. I derive it, and attempt to compare it to zero to find possible extrema:

$$f'(x) = 4\cos(4x) - 4\sin(4x) = 0$$
$$\cos(4x) = \sin(4x)$$

My question — am I allowed to do the following:
$$\sin(4x) = \cos(4x) \quad/\div \cos(4x)$$
$$\tan(4x) = 1$$

From here I can solve for $x$ and get possible extremum points. But notice that it is possible for the divisor to be equal to zero within the provided range, and both the function and derivative are still defined for those points. Is this illegal? Should I instead use trigonometric identities to break down these sort of problems? Alternatively, am I allowed to do this granted I provide a certain explanation?

Comment: You can always treat $\cos(4x)=0$ as a separate case.

Comment: It is not legal in Kansas.

Comment: If $\cos (4x) = 0$, then $|\sin (4x)| = 1$ and so the equation cannot hold. Hence you may safely divide by $\cos(4x)$. (Even if Dorothy disagrees.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, because $$\cos(4x)=0$$ cannot correspond to a solution (this would imply $\sin(4x)=\pm1\ne0$).

---

The usual way to handle such situations is to perform a case study:

- $\cos(4x)=0\to$ impossible;
- $\cos(4x)\ne0\to\tan(4x)=1$.